# Proof that $\sum_{i=1}^n{n \choose i}9^{n-i}i=n10^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I was doing a combinatorics question and I got the LHS of the equation. I noticed that the sum seems to equal the RHS but I'm curious as to how you can prove this. I'd like to know if I can use this result to get a simpler answer to my problem.

Comment: Hello :) Do you know $i\binom ni =n\binom{n-1}{i-1}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to proof it:

**Method 1**

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i\binom{n}{i}\cdot 9^{n-i}}&=n\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\binom{n-1}{i-1}\cdot 9^{n-i}}\\
\\
&=n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n-1}{j}\cdot 9^{n-1-j}}\\
\\
&=n\left(1+9\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

**Method 2: Algebra and binomial theorem**

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\left(x+9\right)^{n}\\
\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}\cdot 9^{n-i}x^{i}}\\
\\
\\
f'(x)&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i\binom{n}{i}\cdot 9^{n-i}x^{i-1}}\\
\\
\\
\sum_{i=0}^{n}{i\binom{n}{i}\cdot 9^{n-i}1^{i-1}}&=f'(1)\\
\\
&=n\left(1+9\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

**Method 3: Combinatorial Proof**

Choose one out of $n$ students to be a captain and then divide the rest into $10$ groups but the groups may have zero members. You can select the captain first and then divide the remaining $n-1$ students into $10$ groups, the number of possibilities is:

$$
n\cdot\left(10\right)^{n-1}
$$

Or you can select some ($i$) students to be excluded from the first nine group, select one captain from these $i$ students then the rest will be in group $10$. Then divide remaining $n-i$ into the first $9$ groups. The number of possibilities is:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}\cdot i\cdot 9^{n-i}}
$$

Since we are only counting the same possibilities using different method, the above two expressions are equal.